# Trying to launch second activity from button click

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to write an android app where I launch a `second activity` from a button click in the `main activity` but I keep getting the error

Error Cannot Find Symbol Method `startActivity(Intent)`
I am stuck and cannot find a way past the above error.

Here is the code from my `PrimaryActivity.Java` file which is the main activity

```js
package com.nickdgreen.beta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;


public class PrimaryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_primary);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_primary, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        
      
        int id = item.getItemId();

      
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PrimaryActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
                startActivty(intent);

            }
        });

      }

    }
```

Comment: You have typo error in `startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing these things :

1. Correct spelling mistake in your code. Its  startActiv**i**ty(intent); and not  startActivty(intent).
2. Make sure your SecondaryActivity is defined in AndroidManifest.xml.
3. Whenever you are invoking main class method from inner class, its better to call with reference of main class. It is not compulsory but its good to avoid confusion and better readability. So make it **PrimaryActivity.this.startActivity(intent)**; .